# What does "scruples of a guinea pig" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

At a basement club scene from *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), Hunsbecker rival columnist
Leo Bartha speaks to Hunsbecker's press agent Sidney:

> Leo:He'll use any spice to pepper up his daily garbage! You tell him I
> said so! Tell him that, like yourself, he's got the **scruples of a
> guinea pig**... and the morals of a gangster.

What does "scruples of a guinea pig" mean?

Comment: Do you know what "scruples" are?  Do you think guinea pigs have any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a feeling that prevents you from doing something that you think is morally wrong or makes you uncertain about doing it [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scruple)

A Guinea pig is an animal with obviously no feeling about "morals", so Leo is saying that he has no understanding of what is right or wrong and has the "morals of a gangster".